# EF6 putting insert parameters in the wrong order

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm working on converting an EF6 EDMX work to EF6 code first, mostly using the existing database structure generated via Visual Studio -> Add Item -> Ado.net Model.

I have the following CF entities:

```
[Table("Account")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MessageUser> MessageUsers { get; set; }

    internal static void ConfigureModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Messages)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Account)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MessageUsers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Account)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

[Table("Message")]
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MessageUser> MessageUsers { get; set; }

    internal static void ConfigureModel(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasMany(e => e.MessageUsers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Message)
            .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.AccountID, e.MessageID })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

[Table("MessageUser")]
public class MessageUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MessageUserID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }

    public virtual Message Message { get; set; }
}
```

In my code I'm adding a user to a message via:

```
        var messageUsers = new List<MessageUser>();
        foreach (var userId in usersInvolved)
        {
            var container = MessageContainer.INBOX;
            if (userId == _serviceContext.UserID)
            {
                container = messageModel.UserIDs.Contains(userId)
                    ? MessageContainer.INBOXANDSENT
                    : MessageContainer.SENT;
            }

            messageUsers.Add(new MessageUser
            {
                Message =  message,
                UserDetailID = userId,
                ParentMessageID = messageModel.ParentMessageID,
                LastUpdatedBy = _serviceContext.UserID,
                LastUpdatedOn = time,
                AccountID = _serviceContext.AccountID,
                Container = container
            });
        }

        DBContext.Message.Add(message);
        DBContext.MessageUser.AddRange(messageUsers);
        DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

This causes a foreign key sql exception between message user and account.  When I load up sql profiler the insert statement that's being generated is

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[MessageUser]([AccountID], [MessageID], [UserDetailID], [ProfileID], [ParentMessageID], [IsRead], [IsTrashed], [LastUpdatedBy], [LastUpdatedOn], [Container])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, NULL, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)
SELECT [MessageUserID], [RowVersionStamp]
FROM [dbo].[MessageUser]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [MessageUserID] = scope_identity() AND [AccountID] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 int,@3 bit,@4 bit,@5 int,@6 datetime2(7),@7 varchar(20)',@0=17293,@1=10015,@2=10092,@3=0,@4=0,@5=11346,@6='2018-10-31 13:44:41.2743099',@7='Inbox'
```

The problem with this is `17293` is the message id and `10015` is the Account ID.  EF6 is putting these parameters in the wrong order and thus it's failing because of FK constraints.  This is extremely concerning because I can't be sure that other inserts are working properly or accidentally working but storing the data wrong.

Is this a bug on my end?

Comment: Can you share the table DDL?

Comment: I'd have to see if I can put together a stripped down DDL.  For now though I've at least determined that EF is just really bad at handling relationships with composite keys as I'm seeing a ton of failing joins all over the place

Comment: Why do you have Account ID included in the [Key]? If you have a unique auto-generated column (MessageUserId) then simply tell EF to use that is the PK. I suspect EF is getting mixed up with the Column Order given that MessageUserId is not present in the insert clauses. I'd suggest trying with just MessageUserId as the Key, then remove the Column Order declarations.

Comment: Because for reasons that predate most sane people coming on this project for the last 2 years every table has a composite primary key that consists of both the `AccountID` and the table's own identity id.  Thus you cannot do joins properly without taking both into consideration.

It's bad but it's how production is today and not easily changed *shrug*.  In the meantime it definitely appears that EF is buggy when it comes to composite primary keys and column ordering.  At some point I need to experiment to see if EF core also has the issues.

Comment: I've gotten a small scale reproduction ready and filed a bug with the EF6 team: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/658

Comment: I really like that design if most of your transactions are for a single AccountId.  It creates good "locality" for related data, and the only real cost is extra typing in joins, and the risk that tools that have difficulty dealing with compound keys.

Comment: IMO it's not good design.  Having the FK data on every table is fine but having them be composite keys means a higher likelyhood of missing one of the keys which will return WRONG results (not just a failed join because of the identity).  You can't easily rely on unique identifiers due to all the composites.  But that's not really the point of this SO.